# Difference between Salesforce application connecting as Site through community vs Pushing into AppExchange

Tags: salesforce, lwc, salesforce-communities

I am a beginner in salesforce and learning salesforce development by using lightning web components. As part of learning we are developing a small scale salesforce LWC application. When we were exploring about the deployment of application , we went through the points regarding with pushing to AppExchange and serving as a Site by going via community setup.

So this makes little bit confusion to us in the concern of , after development how we can deploy this application like how normally we deploying a web application. Do I need to go to community setup and create as site or pushing to appexchange.

So anyone please guide us to make understanding the difference between salesforce site vs appexchange regarding our application deployment or please suggest any documentation to refer ?